# successive approximation in python

Tags: python

Successive approximation is a general method in which on each iteration of an algorithm, we find a closer estimate of the answer for which we are seeking. One class of successive approximation algorithms uses the idea of a fixed point. If f(x) is a mathematical function, then finding the x such that f(x) = x gives us the fixed point of f.

One way to find a fixed point is to start with some guess (e.g. guess = 1.0) and, if this is not good enough, use as a next guess the value of f(guess). We can keep repeating this process until we get a guess that is within epsilon of f(guess).

here's my code:

```
def fixedPoint(f, epsilon):
    """
    f: a function of one argument that returns a float
    epsilon: a small float

    returns the best guess when that guess is less than epsilon 
    away from f(guess) or after 100 trials, whichever comes first.
    """
    guess = 1.0
    for i in range(100):
        if abs(f(guess) - guess) < epsilon:
            return guess
        else:
            guess = f(guess)
    return guess
```

further now...

```
def sqrt(a):
    def tryit(x):
        return 0.5 * (a/x + x)
    return fixedPoint(tryit, 0.0001)
```

I want to compute square root of a number "a", is the fixed point of the function f(x) = 0.5 * (a/x + x). AND DONE.

(Above solutions are correct)

Comment: You probably want `abs(f - guess) < epsilon`, in case f(guess) is much smaller than guess. Also you compute f() twice (once in the if and once in the else: clause), probably want to fix that.

Comment: it's working now. Thank you sir. Kindly bear with me for a moment please. Here's the further code... now I have to compute square root of a number "a" of function f(x) = 0.5*(a/x + x).

def sqrt(a):
    def tryit(x):
        return 0.5 * (a/x + x)
    return fixedPoint(tryit(a), 0.0001)

what's wrong now? :P

Comment: "what's wrong now? :P" You want to pass `tryit` (the function itself) to `fixedPoint`, not `tryit(a)` (i.e. the result of calling the function). The entire point is that `fixedPoint` is supposed to (repeatedly) call `tryit` for you.

Comment: There's no question here.

Answer (score 1):

Successive approximation is a general method in which on each iteration of an algorithm, we find a closer estimate of the answer for which we are seeking. One class of successive approximation algorithms uses the idea of a fixed point. If f(x) is a mathematical function, then finding the x such that f(x) = x gives us the fixed point of f.

One way to find a fixed point is to start with some guess (e.g. guess = 1.0) and, if this is not good enough, use as a next guess the value of f(guess). We can keep repeating this process until we get a guess that is within epsilon of f(guess).

example in python:

```
def fixedPoint(f, epsilon):
"""
f: a function of one argument that returns a float
epsilon: a small float

returns the best guess when that guess is less than epsilon 
away from f(guess) or after 100 trials, whichever comes first.
"""
     guess = 1.0   
     for i in range(100):
           if -epsilon < f(guess) - guess < epsilon:
                  return guess
           else:
                  guess = f(guess)

      return guess
```

further let function f be for finding square root using babylon method:

```
def sqrt(a):
     def babylon(x):
           def test(x):
                return 0.5 * ((a / x) + x)
           return test(x)

     return fixedPoint(babylon, 0.0001)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [optimization and root-finding](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) functions in [scipy](http://www.scipy.org/).

Especially [`scipy.optimize.fixed_point`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fixed_point.html#scipy.optimize.fixed_point). The actual source code is [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/5fd7fc48019c25a804d42d626e5ce67352f2c578/scipy/optimize/minpack.py#L583).